# How to iterate this kind of object with javascript using google charts?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of map from my backend and i would like to loop this list in my map. I tried with a simple for but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
    var message = new Map();
    console.log('je suis le ' + typeof message);
    message = /*[[${liste}]]*/ 'default';
    /*]]>*/

    console.log(typeof message)

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            //for(i=0;i<message.length;i++) {}
            ['Task', 'tranche ages'],

            for(i=0;i<message.length;i++) {
                [Object.keys(message)[i], Object.values(message)[i]];
            }

            // [Object.keys(message)[0], Object.values(message)[0]],
            // [Object.keys(message)[1], Object.values(message)[1]],
            // [Object.keys(message)[2], Object.values(message)[2]],
            // [Object.keys(message)[3], Object.values(message)[3]],
            // [Object.keys(message)[4], Object.values(message)[4]],
            // [Object.keys(message)[5], Object.values(message)[5]]
        ]);
```

[image]

Thnk you in advance for your advices

Comment: Plz provide structure of your input data and also provide how you want it to be as output.

Comment: `nombre de personnes entre 16 et 20 ans: 2
nombre de personnes entre 20 et 30 ans: 5
nombre de personnes entre 30 et 40 ans: 2
nombre de personnes entre 40 et 50 ans: 1`

Comment: the key is a string and the value is a number

Comment: Sorry. didn't understand. Plz provide your list of map structure like `[{key1: val1, ....}]` and your desired output structure as js array or object.

Comment: `
        Map<String, Integer> listeAgesTranches = utilisateurMetier.agesClientsClub(); ` is a map from java

Comment: for exemple `key1 = nombre de personnes entre 16 et 20 ans` and the value is `2`

Comment: Ok. So You will get array of object in javascript like this: `{"nombre de personnes entre 16 et 20 ans": 2, // ... some more elements }`. Now what output you want. you want array of array I think i.e. [ [ "nombre de personnes entre 16 et 20 ans", 2 ] , // ...some more elements ]. Am I right? Plz correct me if I am not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180624/discussion-between-flyordie-and-aagam-jain).

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to use `Object.entries`:

```js
input = {"nombre de personnes entre 16 et 20 ans": 2, "de personnes entre 20 et 30 ans": 5, "de personnes entre 30 et 40 ans": 2, "de personnes entre 40 et 50 ans": 1};

console.log(Object.entries(input));
```

**UPDATE**

For older browsers support don't forget to include [polyfill](https://github.com/es-shims/Object.entries)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can convert object into an array of key - value array.

```js
input = {
  "nombre de personnes entre 16 et 20 ans": 2,
  "nombre de personnes entre 20 et 30 ans": 5,
  "nombre de personnes entre 30 et 40 ans": 2,
  "nombre de personnes entre 40 et 50 ans": 1
};

output = [];

Object.keys(input).forEach(function(d){
  output.push([d, input[d]]);
});

console.log(output);
```